# JS MediaWiki API accessing parsed rows locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, mediawiki

I'm using the MediaWiki API to grab text information from a table on a wiki, so it can be set into a dataset for every row.  I am able to get the table to show up (with rows/columns) on HTML, but I'm not sure how to set the data into an array or other type of dataset locally.
The code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://wiki.teamliquid.net/smash/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&pageid=4887&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
    var i = $('<tbody></tbody>').html(markup);

    // remove any references
    i.find('sup').remove();

    i.find('img').remove(); //remove images 
    i.find('a').each(function() {$(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); }); //remove links 

    x = $('#article').html($(i).find('tr')); //find all rows 
    //console.log(x.parse.text.tr); 
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
    }   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest using page=All_Tournaments instead of setting pageid.
Note that if this code is running inside MediaWiki, you could do something like this instead of $.ajax/$.get:

```
new mw.Api().get( {
    action: 'parse',
    prop: 'text',
    section: 0,
    page: 'All Tournaments'
} ).done( function ( data ) {
    // ...
} );
```

(note this runs the contents of the callback function asynchronously)

But onto your question:

```
var tables = [];
$( i ).find( 'table' ).each( function ( tableId, tableEle ) {
    var tableObjs = [], headers = [];
    $( tableEle ).find( 'th' ).each( function ( i, th ) {
        headers[ i ] = $( th ).text().trim();
    } );

    $i.find( 'tr' ).each( function ( rowId, rowEle ) {
        var row = {};
        $( rowEle ).find( 'td' ).each( function ( i, tdEle ) {
            row[ headers[ i ] ] = $( tdEle ).text().trim();
        } );
        tableObjs[ rowId - 1 ] = row;
    } );
    tables.push( tableObjs );
} );
console.log( tables );
```

This will produce an array of arrays of objects. The outer array is a list of tables, each item is an array of all rows within that table, and each item of that is an object, with the keys being the header that data falls under and the values being the trimmed textual content of the data.